# After selecting variables from lasso regression, is it a good practice to re-run the regression with selected variables?

Tags: regression, least-squares, feature-selection, lasso

As the subject suggests, after selecting regressors from lasso regression, is it a good practice to re-run the an ordinary linearly regression with selected variables?

I just feel like intuitively, this would give a more accurate prediction out of sample. Assuming we addressed the redundant variable problems from lasso, then we should just run a normal regression whose whole target is to minimize prediction error, without extra penalty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a two-stage estimator makes some sense, but you can do better than that. The research on **relaxed lasso** [(Meinshausen, 2007)](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0167947306004956) suggests that having different penalty intensities for variable selection vs. parameter estimation (for a fixed set of variables) can produce sparser models with equal or better predictive performance than standard lasso. You would use a higher penalty intensity for variable selection and a lower intensity for parameter estimation. Actually, this setup is the dominant approach in the recent extensive study of model selection and regularization in linear models by [Hastie et al. (2020)](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/papers/bestsubset-sts.pdf). Meanwhile, reducing the penalty intensity all the way to zero (i.e. doing OLS) in the second stage is generally suboptimal.